# Using celery group throws NotImplementedError

Tags: python-3.x, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I`m trying to call celery tasks from another celery task, here is a example code:

```
from celery import group, allow_join_result


@shared_task
def task1():
   some_code1()

@shared_task
def task2():
   some_code2()

@shared_task
def task3():
    celery_task_list = [task1.s(), task2.s()]
    task_group = group(celery_task_list)
    result_group = task_group.apply_async()
    with allow_join_result():
        results = result_group.join()
    return
```

Running the code throws a NotImplementedError: No result backend is configured.
ignore_result=True doesnt help

I want to call several others tasks from 1 celery task, then wait for their execution and after perform some actions. Is this achivable without configirung the backend?([similar issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6197), there even configured result backend doesnt help)